# Django 1.8: How use Model from different application?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8

My problem is I want to create something like `common-application` (this can be also a standard Python Module) with e.g.:

- `Model_1`
- `Model_2`
- `Model_3`

And also create `application_1` and `application_2` where models from `common-application` being used by this e.g.:

- `application_1`

  - `Model_1`
  - `Model_2`
  - `Model_4` - *app specific additional model*
- `application_2`

  - `Model_1`
  - `Model_2`
  - `Model_3`

Really I don't know how `models.py` and `apps.py` should look like.. :/

Is it possible ?

PS. And If I want to write `DATABASE_ROUTER` to split this applications between two databases makes this problem really impossible to solve ?

Comment: I've got this problem because I've 40+ common models to create :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the common models in `common_application`'s models.py file as an abstract model, by adding the following to the model's class:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Then, in other applications you can import your common models like so:

```
from common_application.models import Model_1, Model_2, Model_3
```

And then instantiate model classes that will derive from the abstract model class:

```
class Model_1a(Model_1):
```

More details on Model class inheritance can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/)

Comment: and they will be created by `django syncdb`? how about migrations? Maybe in `common` set up them as `abstract=True`  and in `app_1` simple inherit them?

Comment: As long as `common_application` is part of your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file, syncdb should create those models. Why would you want to make them abstract?

Comment: because I don't want to create them in `common_app`

Comment: Not sure I'm following the rationale. Is `Model_1` used in `application_1` the same model as `Model_1` used in `application_2`? If yes, then you'll have to derived the abstract model in one of the apps and use it in both. This would defeat the purpose of putting an abstract model in `common_app`.

Comment: No, I want only definition on `common` but two different instances (but the same definition): one for `app_1` and second for `app_2`

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - you won't query `Model_1` across the applications. Only within each of the applications. If this is the case, then your plan to make `Model_1` abstract in `common_app` and instantiate it in each of the applications sounds like the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
application1
    models (directory - package)
        __init__.py
        model1.py
        model2.py
        model3.py
```

Into **init**.py files you could import all models from model*.py

```
from model1 import *
from model2 import *
from model3 import *
```

Also with models Meta you can set db_tablespace (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a model from one app to another app
For Example First App Model look like this
[This is the first modal that I want to use in the different app look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXXBu.jpg)

In the second model in a different app, it depends where you want to use that modal, for my case I use that model in view.py to retrieve information
[In this view import your model by writing from {yourappname}.models import {modelname}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95ai3.jpg)